# Are there any CakePHP Email Plugin/Compnonents?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am building an application that will need to send emails on numerous occasions like Account activation, password reset link and various other notifications.

I am using Cakephp 1.3.2.

Would prefer a plugin or component where I can create templates and just pass variables and it sends an email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use CakePHP's default functionality?

http://book.cakephp.org/view/269/Sending-a-basic-message

Comment: Agreed.  Seems like Harsha didn't RTM :(.  @Harsha -- Cake has a built in EmailComponent.  The Bakery has many other "enhanced" versions, some of which have tie-ins with the heavy duty SwiftMailer libraries.

Comment: i knew of the email component. didnt knew of the templates :(

Answer (score 1):

In the past I used SwiftMailer: http://swiftmailer.org/ It's an excellent, flexible and well documented component with a cakephp component available in the bakery: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/swiftmailer-component-tutorial

Now, though, I usually use the CakePHP core component.

Comment: guess cakephp email component is powerfull enuf for basic stuff.